# How to use S3 (AWS SDK v3) to cache images generated by LiipImagineBundle

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, dependency-injection, liipimaginebundle

I'm trying to use the S3 Cache Resolver of `LiipImagineBundle` to upload my cached thumbnails to S3 but I'm exepriencing some strange issues.

I'm using the AWS SDK v ^3.2:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.2",
```

I'm using Symfony2 and in my `services.yml`, I've configured the `Aws\Credentials\Credentials` class and the `Aws\S3\S3Client` that uses it to create the client:

```
shq.amazon.s3Credentials:
    class: Aws\Credentials\Credentials
    arguments: ["%amazon.s3.key%", "%amazon.s3.secret%"]

shq.amazon.s3:
    class: Aws\S3\S3Client
    arguments:
        - version: %amazon.s3.version%
          region: %amazon.s3.region%
          credentials: "@shq.amazon.s3Credentials"
```

All works well, and I'm able to upload files to S3.

Now, the configuration of `LiipImagineBundle`: **it seems that `LiipImagineBundle` has configuration rules that apply only to AWS SDK 2 and that causes "false positives" using the `aws_s3` cache resolver.**

I've tried at least three different configurations.

**CONFIGURATION 1: FOR AWS SDK 2**

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path: ~
        cache_s3:
           aws_s3:
               client_config:
                    key:    %amazon.s3.key%
                    secret: %amazon.s3.secret%
                    region: %amazon.s3.region%
                    version: %amazon.s3.version%
               bucket: %amazon.s3.bucket%
               get_options:
                   Scheme: 'https'
               put_options:
                   CacheControl: 'max-age=86400'

    cache: cache_s3

    filter_sets:
        thumb_purchase:
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [250, 250], mode: outbound }
                interlace:
                    mode: line
```

This throws an exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata
>   server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1006 milliseconds
>   (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))") in
>   src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Store/show.html.twig at line 135.

This is thrown by the AWS SDK that is [searching for credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/basic-usage.html#creating-a-client) and doesn't find them.

So, this approach seems not working.

**CONFIGURATION 2: USING `Aws\Credentials` (AWS SDK 3)**

The way to pass credentials to `S3Client` is passing an instance of `Aws\Credentials`. I do this through a service so I can reuse the same credentials in other services (and that works as I use it to upload files to S3!):

```
shq.amazon.s3Credentials:
    class: Aws\Credentials\Credentials
    arguments: ["%amazon.s3.key%", "%amazon.s3.secret%"]
```

and in `config.yml` the :

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       cache_thumb_purchase:
           aws_s3:
               client_config:
                    version: %amazon.s3.version%
                    region: %amazon.s3.region%
                    credentials: "@shq.amazon.s3Credentials"
               bucket: %amazon.s3.bucket%
               get_options:
                   Scheme: 'https'
               put_options:
                   CacheControl: 'max-age=86400'
    filter_sets:
        thumb_purchase:
            cache: cache_thumb_purchase
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [250, 250], mode: outbound } # Transforms 50x40 to 32x26, no cropping
                interlace:
                    # mode can be one of none,line,plane,partition
                    mode: line
```

As you can see, I pass the `Credentials` service to `LiipImagineBundle` but I get this error FROM `Aws\ClientResolver`:

> InvalidArgumentException in ClientResolver.php line 296:
>   Invalid configuration value provided for "credentials". Expected Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface|array|bool|callable, **but got string '@shq.amazon.s3Credentials' *(length=25)***
>
> credentials: (Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface|array|bool|callable)
>
> Specifies the credentials used to sign requests. Provide an
>   Aws\Credentials\CredentialsInterface object, an associative array of "key",
>   "secret", and an optional "token" key, `false` to use null credentials, or
>   a callable credentials provider used to create credentials or return null.
>   See Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider for a list of built-in credentials
>   providers. If no credentials are provided, the SDK will attempt to load
>   them from the environment.

**It seems that, instead of passing the class `Credentials` referenced by `@shq.amazon.s3Credentials`, it passes simply the string `@shq.amazon.s3Credentials`, so the `ClientResolver`, correctly, reports that the passed parameter is incorrect.**

So, this configuration doesn't work, too.

**CONFIGURATION 3: PASSING AN ARRAY TO `S3Client` (AWS SDK 3)**

The third way of instantiating a `S3Client` is [passing an associative array to hardcode credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/credentials.html#using-hard-coded-credentials).

So I tried this configuration:

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
       cache_thumb_purchase:
           aws_s3:
               client_config:
                    version: %amazon.s3.version%
                    region: %amazon.s3.region%
                    #credentials: "@shq.amazon.s3Credentials"
                    credentials:
                        key: %amazon.s3.key%
                        secret: %amazon.s3.secret%
    ...
```

**But this time I receive an error from `LiipImagineBundle`, that seems doesn't accept an array as parameter:**

> InvalidTypeException in ScalarNode.php line 36: Invalid type for path
>   "liip_imagine.resolvers.cache_thumb_purchase.aws_s3.client_config.HERE_THERE_IS_DIRECTLY_MY_AWS_KEY".
>   **Expected scalar, but got array.**

I think that the configuration rules of the bundle have to be updated but i don't know how to do this as I'm not yet so confident with such kind of things.

**So, how can I make `LiipImagineBundle` / Symfony to pass the class instead of the string that refers to the `Credentials`class? Is a fault of mine, or is something broken in `LiipImagineBundle`?**

(Also, strange thing that I don't understand, instead of using the term "key" in the path, it use the value of "key" that is `HERE_THERE_IS_DIRECTLY_MY_AWS_KEY`.
So it reports a path like this `liip_imagine.resolvers.cache_thumb_purchase.aws_s3.client_config.HERE_THERE_IS_DIRECTLY_MY_AWS_KEY`instead of a path like `liip_imagine.resolvers.cache_thumb_purchase.aws_s3.client_config.key` - that to me seems more correct, doesn't it?).

Comment: check this approach: https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/issues/496

Comment: I've read that issue, but it seems to be for the AWS SDK v2, not for the v3.

It returns me this: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1006 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))") in src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Myview/show.html.twig at line 135."

Comment: I've updated the question including also the test with that configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        cache_thumb_purchase:
            aws_s3:
                client_config:
                    credentials:
                        key:    %amazon.s3.key%
                        secret: %amazon.s3.secret%
                    version: %amazon.s3.version%
                    region: %amazon.s3.region%
                bucket: %amazon.s3.bucket%
                get_options:
                    Scheme: 'https'
                put_options:
                    CacheControl: 'max-age=86400'
    filter_sets:
        thumb_purchase:
            cache: cache_thumb_purchase
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [250, 250], mode: outbound } # Transforms 50x40 to 32x26, no cropping
                interlace:
                    # mode can be one of none,line,plane,partition
                    mode: line


services:
    admin.amazon.s3:
        class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_class: Aws\S3\S3Client
        factory_method: 'factory'
        arguments:
            - key: %amazon.s3.key%
              secret: %amazon.s3.secret%
              region: %amazon.s3.region%
              version: %amazon.s3.version%
```

I'm starting to work on this `LiipImagineBundle` + `KnpGaufretteBundle` + `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.18"` right now